# I need to load images into a simple GUI for fingerprint recognition in MATLAB but only ONE image is been loaded successfyully

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-figure, fingerprint

Whenever i try to load any other image except a specific image '1.bmp' given below, the following errors are shown:
Error using image
TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0

Error in imagesc (line 19)
    hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

The code used for loading the image into GUI is as follows:

```
function image1=loadimage

[imagefile1 , pathname]= uigetfile('*.bmp;*.BMP;*.tif;*.TIF;*.jpg','Open An Fingerprint image');   
if imagefile1 ~= 0  
cd(pathname);  
image1=readimage(char(imagefile1));  
image1=255-double(image1);

end;
```

Is there a problem in the code or is it because of the image size and resolution ?

the image which is succesfully loaded is:
![fingerprint(300*300)]

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the code you provided but occurs when trying to display the image.

Without seeing that code I can't say for certain but I suspect you try and display image1 which is still image RGB data (i.e nxmx3 matrix). However, you have done `image1=255-image1`.
Therefore, the RGB data will no longer be in the range 0-255.

Imagesc and most other matlab display function can either display a grayscale image or RGB values in the range 0-255. If they are not in this range an error is thrown.

Either display you image before the subtraction or convert it to grey-scale before displaying.